¿Cómo configurar un campo autoincrementable de 10 en 10 en MySQL?
Necesito realizar desde la consola de MySQL, la configuración de un campo autoincrementable con un incremento de 10 en 10. No sé si esto sea posible en MySQL.
He visto que se puede definir el valor con el que comienzan los registros, pero no he encontrado cómo incrementar cada registro de 10 en 10 y no de 1 en 1.

Segun esto parece que la restricción IDENTITY (que hace que se autoincremente el id) acepta dos argumentos, la semilla inicial y el incremento. Te quedaria algo asi: CREATE TABLE libros (id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,10) PRIMARY KEY);

@Mady Tengo entendido que usar IDENTITY es en SQL Server. Lo he probado en MySQL y marca error.

Para comenzar con un valor AUTO_INCREMENT distinto de 1, establezca ese valor con CREATE TABLE o ALTER TABLE, así:
mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;

Según la página de MySql
Y para los siguientes valores
CREATE TABLE `tabla`(
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
...
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 10, INCREMENT = 10;


Al ejecutar la segunda sentencia me marca error con la palabra increment.

yo pude encontrar la solución para mi caso aquí, checa si esa opción te sirve saludos
AUTO_INCREMENT en MySQL
